# How to configure yarn so that it shows output from webpack? webpack --display-error-details

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, yarnpkg

webpack fails with errors, I want to investigate why it fails.

```
ERROR in ./~/react-navigation/lib/views/HeaderBackButton.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/back-icon.png' in '/home/xxx/projects/react-native-web-boilerplate/node_modules/react-navigation/lib/views'
 @ ./~/react-navigation/lib/views/HeaderBackButton.js 73:18-51
 @ ./~/react-navigation/lib/react-navigation.js
 @ ./src/navigation.js
 @ ./index.web.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/only-dev-server react-hot-loader/patch ./index.web.js
```

I know the command to do that.

```
webpack --display-error-details
```

However, I don't know to configure yarn to display webpack error details.

This is how I usually run my project.

```
cd project
yarn
yarn web
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any flags to the underlying command by putting them after `--`. The double dash indicates the end of command options, and yarn will realise that everything after it should be passed to the command/script you're executing.

Assuming you have the following scripts in your `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
  "web": "webpack --progress --config custom.config.js"
}
```

When you run:

```
yarn web -- --display-error-details
```

Yarn will effectively run:

```
webpack --progress --config custom.config.js --display-error-details
```

It allows you to add any arguments/options while still running the same basic command. This can be desired as shown with the above example, where you always want to have the `--config custom.config.js` option.

If you only want to run a locally installed executable without creating a script, you can do it in one of the following ways.

```sh
yarn webpack -- --display-error-details
# Or
yarn run webpack -- --display-error-details
```

The `run` command is optional, but be aware that when a built-in command exist it will run that instead of a script/executable. Yarn looks for an existing command in this order:

1. Built-in command
2. Script in `package.json`
3. Executable in `./node_modules/.bin/`

With `run` it will skip the first step, allowing you to run a script with the same name as a built-in command. If you have a script `clean`, which for instance removes any built files, these two are not identical, because yarn has a [`clean`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/clean) command.

```sh
yarn clean      # yarn's built-in clean
yarn run clean  # your script
```